# Instance variables and threading with GCD

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, ios5, grand-central-dispatch

I recently added threading to an app so that network requests are not blocking the UI.  On doing this, I discovered that I could no longer set my instance variable the same way as I had before implementing threading.  My instance variable is a property declared as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *currentTopPlaces;
```

Here is how I incorrectly set my instance variable self.currentTopPlaces:

```
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Flickr Top Places Downloader", NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
    __block NSArray *topPlaces = [FlickrFetcher topPlaces];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.tableRowCount = [topPlaces count];
        [[self currentTopPlaces] setArray:topPlaces];
    });
```

Using [self currentTopPlace] setArray:topPlaces] worked fine in the blocking version, before I started using GCD.

Now, I must set it like so for things to work correctly:

```
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Flickr Top Places Downloader", NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
    __block NSArray *topPlaces = [FlickrFetcher topPlaces];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.tableRowCount = [topPlaces count];
        self.currentTopPlaces = topPlaces;
    });
```

Can someone explain to me the difference between using:

```
[[self currentTopPlaces] setArray:topPlaces];
```

and:

```
self.currentTopPlaces = topPlaces;
```

Specifically, why the "setArray" call did not work in a threaded block?

I thought dot notation in Objective-C is syntactic sugar and not mandatory.  I would like to know the "non-sugared" way to achieve the same behavior.

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work"?  Please be specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[self currentTopPlaces]` and `self.currentTopPlaces` are in fact identical, but

```
[self.currentTopPlaces setArray:topPlaces]; // (1)
self.currentTopPlaces = topPlaces; // (2)
```

are not. (1) replaces all elements of `self.currentTopPlaces` with those from `topPlaces`. (2)  assigns a new value to `self.currentTopPlaces` (releasing the old value if it was not *nil*).

A difference occurs if  `self.currentTopPlaces` is *nil*: (1) does nothing, because the `setArray:` method is sent to *nil*. (2) assigns a new value to `self.currentTopPlaces`.

Btw: The `__block` modifier is not necessary in your code, because the block will not change the value of `topPlaces`.

Answer (score 2):

```
[[self currentTopPlaces] setArray:topPlaces];
self.currentTopPlaces = topPlaces;
```

These are two entirely different expressions.   The first is as written, the second would be:

```
[self setCurrentTopPlaces:topPlaces];
```

If you want to do the first one with dot notation, it would be:

```
self.currentTopPlaces.array = topPlaces;
```

Comment: Thanks, I see the difference now, but I guess I'm still not understanding why setArray seemingly "worked" in the non-threaded version, but not in the threaded version.  The setArray documentation says, "Sets the receiving array’s elements to those in another given array.."  When setCurrentTopPlaces is used, won't it also set it's elements to those of the other array--in this case topPlaces?  When setCurrentTopPlaces is used, there must be something else happening in addition to that, right?

Comment: @FabrizioMachado: What exactly does not work with `setArray` in the threaded version?

Comment: @MartinR:  after calling setArray, currentTopPlaces is still empty in the threaded version.

Comment: @FabrizioMachado: I think that I explained that in my answer. If `self.currentTopPlaces` is nil, then `setArray` will have no effect.

Comment: @MartinR:  Thank you.  I did not see your answer, but it all makes sense now.  Accepted.